# Finder shows different file size compared to terminal

Tags: terminal, mac, finder, unix, filesystem

I have a folder called 'objects' in my mac.

When I check the contents of it in the terminal it's showing like this.
[image: Image from terminal]

Clearly object folder shows 4.1K

However when I see it in the finder,

[image: Image from the finder]

It shows, 26.3 MB

What's the reason for the significant increase in the size in the finder?

Comment: What did you alias `ls` to? The output you show is not standard for a simple `ls`.

Comment: @nohillside I have aliased ls to 'ls -lh'

Comment: The image shows a file size of 25.7 MB but in the text you write 26.3 MB. Where did the last figure come from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to enter the command `du -sh *` instead of `ls` to get the actual size of the folders in your current directory (the sum of the files size they contain).

The command `ls` shows file size, but it has a different meaning for folders. It actually shows the size allocated for the directory to store metadata (mainly the index) of the files it contains.

Comment: Oh. When I try to transfer the folder to drive, it's actually transferring the entire 26 MB. Is there anyway I can transfer only the actual file size i.e. 4KB?

Comment: @Prajwal 26 MB is the actual size of your folder with all its content. The only way to reduce its size is to compress it.

Comment: @Prajwal you can remove the contents of the folder and only transfer that. Then Finder and ls wound agree on the size.

Comment: @Tim And nuke the git metadata at the same time?